# Can't overwrite object saved with rhaboo in javascript

Tags: javascript, jquery, local-storage

I'm trying to save an object with rhaboo in javascript. The first time after initialising it is working but when I'm trying to save it again it gives me the 
`rhaboo.min.js:1 Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'refs' of undefined` error. I pinned down the error to the line where I save the `keyArray` with `notes.write('presentationNotes', keyArray);`

How I get the error in detail:
I open my webapplication with a clean localStorage (nothing is saved) and rhaboo gets initialised. After that I navigate to a document and open the `notes-div` with the `notes-button`. I write something in the `notes-area` and hit the `notes-submit` button to save the notes with rhaboo to localStorage. I do the same for a second document. For now everything works. Both notes get saved correctly so that I have an object like this:

`keyArray = {activeDoc1: ['note1', 'note2'], activeDoc2: ['note1', 'note2']}`

saved in rhaboo in `notes.presentationNotes`. Then I reload my webapplication and rhaboo is already initialised. I navigate to the documents as before and check if I can load the saved notes. This works as expected but when I try to hit the `notes-submit` button again it gives me the aforementioned error. What am I doing wrong?

```
var notes = Rhaboo.persistent('Presentation Notes');

$(document).ready(function(event) {
var keyArray, activeDoc;

if (!notes.initialised) {
    notes.write('initialised', true);
    notes.write('presentationNotes', {});
    console.log('Rhaboo Initialised');
    keyArray = {};
} else {
    console.log('Rhaboo already initialised');
    keyArray = notes.presentationNotes;
    console.log('notes.presentationNotes onLoad = ');
    console.log(notes.presentationNotes);
}

//Notes open
$(document).on('click', '#notes-button', function() {
    $('.notes-div').show();
    activeDoc = $('.node.active').attr('id');
    if (notes.presentationNotes[activeDoc] != null) {
        //Iterate notes
        $.each(notes.presentationNotes[activeDoc], function(index, value) {
            $('#notes-area').append(value + '\n');
        });
    }
});

//Notes save
$(document).on('click', '#notes-submit', function() {
    $('.notes-div').hide();
    var str = $('#notes-area').val();
    var array = str.split("\n");
    keyArray[activeDoc] = array;

    //Save notes
    notes.write('presentationNotes', keyArray);

    //Clear textarea
    $('#notes-area').val('');
});
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Without the HTML I haven't been able to try this, so I'm just guessing here, but I suspect your problem will go away if you stop using keyArray and activeDoc. The whole point of rhaboo is that it is not a place to store your data. It *IS* your data.

I see no transient data in your program, i.e., no data which you actively want to delete when the user goes away and comes back. All the data is supposed to be persistent, therefore it should all be under the Rhaboo.persistent.

That's the philosophy, but to be more specific, I think your problem is here:

```
keyArray[activeDoc] = array;
```

When I wonder what keyArray is is find:

```
keyArray = notes.presentationNotes;
```

so the earlier line actually says:

```
notes.presentationNotes[activeDoc] = array;
```

but it says on the tin that that should read:

```
notes.presentationNotes.write(activeDoc, array);
```

The upshot is that that the hooks that make rhaboo work have not been inserted into array, as notes.presentationNotes.write would have done.

When you next said:

```
notes.write('presentationNotes', keyArray);
```

it meant:

```
notes.write('presentationNotes', notes.presentationNotes).
```

which is clearly not what you meant. Rhaboo doesn't suspect that array has no hooks yet because it can see that notes.presentationNotes does have hooks.

I also forget to use write sometimes, and it really bugs me that JS offers no way to hook into the creation of a *NEW* key within an object X, no matter what you've done to X. Without that limitation, there'd be no need for write and it could be foolproof.